# I want to fusion the product columns in email table order

Tags: php, customization, woocommerce-offtopic, email

I have an E-commerce apparel Website (for T-shirts and hoodies, etc...)
with a design studio.
The customer can order products in 2 ways… either a blank product without entering the designer studio by clicking the “Add to Cart” button which is on the Product Detail page and.
Or by entering to the designer studio by clicking the “start design” button

**The problem**: When I receive a customized apparel order in my email box, It shows a duplicate column. (The picture and the note will help you to understand)
So I want to fusion the columns  that belong to each other(See the yellow part in the note) and delete the duplicated data like ( name and price of the product.)
[image] [image]

Comment: You'd probably do best asking your design studio. Do you know where this email is generated, and from what template or in which code? You haven't told us enough information to guess this for you.

Comment: I asked my design studio, but they said they can't do that, It's a Plugin called Lumise (which is the designer) and linked to the Woocommerce plugin, the customer and the administrator receive this email when the customer place in new order.. it's a php code